# Verilog - Do I need to add delay with two always situation and also do always(*) sensitive to same input?

Tags: verilog

1) If I have two always block like:

```
input [3:0] m1;
reg [3:0] m1_r;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    m1_r = m1_r >> 2; //or #5 m1_r = m1_r >> 2;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    m1_r <= m1;
end
```

Do I need to delay for a small time to make sure that the m1's value has already load into m1_r?

2) If I use always @(*) block. Will this block be executed twice if I have the same input for two times? Or it just sensitive to different values?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer to your question is no, but it really depends oh how your driving m1. Small delays are for simulation only and are not synthesisable.

Comment: What hardware are you trying to describe with `m1_r` being set be two processes(blocks)? you could just do ` m1_r = m1 >> 2;`

Comment: @Morgan I have just understood the module I wrote above is incorrect. It should use always @(*). Thanks!

Comment: I think there is still an issue with what you are trying to do. You are setting m1_r in two blocks either way you can not do this. You need to think about the hardware circuit you are describing.

Comment: @Morgan This just a example I make up. I just want to figure out in which scenario should use @(*) and which should use @(posedge clk). Nevermind :)

Comment: Well  `@(posedge clk)` implies a filp-flop, and `@*` is combinatorial (everything else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, never make assignments to single variable in two different `always` blocks. This may result in race-around conditions and cause adverse effects in synthesis.

Referring to the trial code, you can not use always@* here due to some common reasons. This is a combinational circuit, for which the output should change whenever the RHS variables changes.

[image: Verilog Event Regions]

Here, when `m1` changes, this block assigns the value to `m1_r` in NBA region (due to non-blocking assignment). Again, since m1_r changes in NBA region, the block executes second time; going into active region. This goes on forever on a single time stamp (Refer to the feedback path in image). Hence, either remove the non-blocking assignment or avoid using `always @*`. The code I am referring to is as below.

```
  always @(*) begin
    m1_r <= m1;
    m1_r = m1_r >> 2; //or #5 m1_r = m1_r >> 2;
  end
```

On the other hand, using `always @(posedge clk)` includes only `clk` in the sensitivity list.  This will infer to a flip-flop.
The block will execute only once at the edge of clock. But, here also, use of non-blocking assignments and single `always` block is recommended.